# Onclick is called twice

Tags: javascript, onclick

Here's the code:

```
<label onclick="event.stopPropagation(); alert(event.target.innerHTML);">
    <button>
        button
    </button> 
    <span>
        span
    </span>
</label>
```

(and the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YsYKq/1/)

If one clicks on the button, only `button` is alerted, but when on span - both `span` and `button` are alerted - so the `onclick` function is called twice.

How can I prevent this? I need `onclick` to be called only once.

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` instead of `event.stopPropagation();` seems to give the clicked element only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`event.preventDefault();` instead of `event.stopPropagation();` triggers `onclick` on the clicked element only. A demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bYVSc/).

Answer (score 5):

Please try below code i am editing your code and change "stopPropagation" to "preventDefault".

```
<label onclick="event.preventDefault(); alert(event.target.innerHTML);">
    <button>
        button
    </button> 
    <span>
        span
    </span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion by @BenM Goes Perfect But if you still want to use  enclosing button and span then here's a way...

```
<label for="notExistingId" onclick="event.stopPropagation(); alert(event.target.innerHTML);">
<button>
    button
</button> 
<span>
    span
</span>
```

**Just provide a value of 'for' in label with an ID which do not exist.**

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

...click event gets fired twice when user click on any of the item in iscroll...

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/iscroll/XL2Ny9gpKc0

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using different id field for label and checkbox - and then testing event.target.label for label script

function selectIconElement(elem, event){

```
if(event.target.id.indexOf('label')>0){
    //do something if its label
}else{
    //do something if not label
}
```

}